# connected graphs with 4 vertices up to isomorphism

Tags: graph-theory

How many distinct connected graphs (up to isomorphism) are there on 4 vertices which do not contain a $K_3$ subgraph?

I think the answer is 3? Because there are 2 non-isomorphic trees on 4 unlabeled vertices plus one shaped like a quadrilateral. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you're right. http://www.graphclasses.org/smallgraphs.html#nodes4

Comment: @ 79037662  Hi I don't quite get what the link says. I got a formula on the number of graphs with n vertices to be 2^(n(n-1)/2)?

Comment: but the link says there are only 11 graphs with 4 vertices...

Comment: Yes, you can examine the 11 graphs and notice exactly 3 have the properties you desired.

Comment: @ 79037662  I mean should there be like 2^(4(4-1)/2)=64 graphs with 4 vertices? How come the link says there are only 11 of them?

Comment: There are that many graphs on labelled vertices, but only 11 up to isomorphism.

Comment: I don't believe there is a simple closed form expression, but here is the OEIS link: https://oeis.org/A000088

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're correct. First, if the graph contains a cycle, it must be a 4-cycle - otherwise it would absolutely contain a triangle. Then, since it is connected, any other graph must be a tree; which as you pointed out can only be one of two possibilities.